# Как преобразовать переменную в байты

Tags: python, python-3.x, byte

Возник вопрос. Можно перевести строку в байты так:

```
b"qwerty"
```

но как сделать чтобы вместо `qwerty` была переменная?

Comment: Вы хотите переменную в байты перевести? Или полученную строку присвоить к переменной?

Comment: Или всё-таки строку?

Comment: @Tehnorobot переменную в байты

Comment: @dontHacker1234 так нельзя делать, лучше используйте переменную в качестве носителя строки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да много вариантов есть. В дополнение к предыдущим:

Раз:

```
a=bytes('Строка байт', encoding = 'utf-8')
b=a
print (b)
b'\xd0\xa1\xd1\x82\xd1\x80\xd0\xbe\xd0\xba\xd0\xb0 \xd0\xb1\xd0\xb0\xd0\xb9\xd1\x82'
```

Два:

```
a='Это будет строка байт'.encode('utf-8')
b = bytearray(a)
print (b)
bytearray(b'\xd0\xad\xd1\x82\xd0\xbe \xd0\xb1\xd1\x83\xd0\xb4\xd0\xb5\xd1\x82 \xd1\x81\xd1\x82\xd1\x80\xd0\xbe\xd0\xba\xd0\xb0 \xd0\xb1\xd0\xb0\xd0\xb9\xd1\x82')
```

Или даже так: именно "готовая" переменная -  в байты:

```
t='Строка байт'
a=bytes(t, encoding = 'utf-8')
print (a)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = "qwerty"
a = a.encode()
```

Возвращает байтовый объект с кодировкой utf-8 по умолчанию.
Принимает следующие аргументы:

```
str.encode(encoding="utf-8", errors="strict")
```

Документация
https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так

```
>>> hello = 'привет'

>>> hello_bytes = hi.encode('utf-8')
>>> print(hello_bytes)
b'\xd0\xbf\xd1\x80\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb5\xd1\x82'
>>> 
>>> 
>>> print(hello_bytes.decode('utf-8'))
привет
>>>
```